# Python 3: vehicle inventory using class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having trouble getting my Python program to work for my class assignment. I have written what I think is the correct code but I still get errors like:

```
*NameError: name 'self' is not defined* Here is the Assignment:
```

Create a final program that meets the requirements outlined below.

Create an automobile class that will be used by a dealership as a vehicle inventory program.  The following attributes should be present in your automobile class:

- private string make
- private string model
- private string color
- private int year
- private int mileage

Your program should have appropriate methods such as:

- constructor
- add a new vehicle
- remove a vehicle
- update vehicle attributes

At the end of your program, it should allow the user to output all vehicle inventory to a text file.

Below is my code and any help is appreciated:

```
    class Automobile:

    def __init__(self, make, model, color, year, mileage):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.color = color
        self.year = year
        self.mileage = mileage

    def add_vehicle(self):
        auto = Automobile()
        vehicle_file = open('vehicle.txt', 'a')
        make = input("Enter make: ")
        model = input("Enter model: ")
        color = input("Enter color: ")
        year = input("Enter year: ")
        mileage = input("Enter mileage: ")

        vehicles = Automobile(make, model, color, year, mileage)
        vehicle_list = [vehicles.make, vehicles.model, vehicles.color, vehicles.year, vehicles.mileage]

        for i in vehicle_list:
            vehicle_file.write("%s\t" % item)
            vehicle_file.write("\n")
            vehicle_file.close()
        print("Your record has been succesfully added to the inventory")

    def delete_vehicle(self):
        del_rec = input("Enter record to delete: ")

        with open("vehicle.txt","r+") as f:
            new_f = f.readlines()
            f.seek(0)
            for line in new_f:
                if del_rec not in line:
                    f.write(line)
            f.truncate()
        print("Succesfully deleted record from inventory")

    def set_make(self, make):
        self.make = make

    def get_make(self):
        return self.make

    def set_model(self, model):
        self.model = model

    def get_model(self):
        return self.model

    def set_color(self, color):
        self.color = color

    def get_color(self):
        return self.color

    def set_year(self, year):
        self.year = year

    def get_year(self):
        return self.year

    def set_mileage(self, mileage):
        self.mileage = mileage

    def get_mileage(self):
        return self.mileage

def main():
    menu = {}
    menu['1']="Add Vehicle." 
    menu['2']="Delete Vehicle."
    menu['3']="Find Vehicle"
    menu['4']="Exit"

user=True
while user:
    print ("""
    1.Add a Vehicle
    2.Delete a Vehicle
    3.View Inventory
    4.Exit/Quit
    """)
    ans=input("What would you like to do? ") 
    if ans=="1": 
      Automobile.add_vehicle
    elif ans=="2":
      Automobile.delete_vehicle(self)
    elif ans=="3":
      print(Automobile.vehicles) 
    elif ans=="4":
      print("\n Goodbye")
      break
    elif ans !="":
      print("\n Invaild Entry")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Take `auto = Automobile()` away from `def add_vehicle`  - you create a new instance of an object outside of the object - in either global or method scope but not in the object itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are importing this module you have created and using it in main, it works fine for me. The only thing you need to change is to change i to item in your for loop, and remove the self in delete vehicle all the way at the bottom. This removed all of the errors for me from your class. Also Please do note that if you are supposed to be using private and protected variables you need to add for ex: __self.Make. Your variables are currently not private or protected. by adding the _ or __ modifier you make the variables private or protected. I'm guessing you have a vague idea of what private and protected do, but that's why you need the getter and setters. give that a shot and see if it helps! also if you are still unclear please make sure to look back over private and protected variables. also not sure if your add vehicle method will work at the bottom because you didn't close the parentheses. it should be addvehicle()

Comment: Thanks for your help! with this and a little more research I was able to get it working.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: The changes you suggest don't actually make the program work; the `i`/`item` change is good, but removing `self` from the `delete_vehicle` call just changes one wrong thing to a different wrong thing, and there are plenty of other problems. Also, `_` and `__` do not work like `private` or `protected`, and as far as the similarities go, you have them switched around; `__` is more similar to `private`, and `_` is more similar to `protected`.

Comment: user thanked me for my response so im not sure why you are telling me the answer is wrong, also i didnt specify which worked like private and which worked like protected. simply said _ or __ make the variables either private or protected. again though, user has already fixed his issue with my support.

Comment: also self is to be understood as an instance argument without being written. so having self there actually is a problem, removing it was the solution. You also probably haven't considered that the OP is using a main module to run this program. Please provide a fully validated code template if you are further concerned and clarify for both of us :)